# Passing server side data to JavaScript - Scriplet or AJAX call - which is better?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, scriptlet

In a property file at server side I'm maintaining a comma separated list of words.

```
words.for.js=some,comma,separated,words
```

I want to create a JavaScript array out of these words.

```
var words = [some,comma,separated,words];
```

I thought of two options

1.Using a JSP scriplet, create a global variable

```
<%  
    out.print("<script> var words = [");
    out.print( PropertyLoader.getAsCommaSeparated("words.for.js") );
    out.print(" ] </script>");
%>
```

2.Expose a service/ action (i.e. /getWords.do ) and call this using AJAX and construct the array.

I'm not sure which is better of the two and appreciate your thoughts here.
Or is there any better way to do this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is also a comparison of global JS variable (in case of option 1) vs additional http request (in case of option 2) - which one is worse. I would like to know your thoughts from this perspective as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer embedding the server-side data within your JSP's markup - #1.  It is faster and doesn't require a callback.

For me, it is all about the nature of the data.  In your case, the data in that properties file seems unlikely to change without a server reboot.  So, saving an additional network callback and embedding it into the markup feels appropriate for a global variable.

If you were dealing with some sort of dynamic data, an ajax callback onload would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing through an http request would be the most elegant option and would allow for refreshes. You are already counting on the browser having javascript, anyway.

Also, if the value is not dynamic, why not just serve a static javascript file with the array in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JSON? since all you need is to send some string to front end. Something like this:

```
String [] s = {"test","test1"};
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(s);
request.setAttribute("test", array);
```

JSP

```
<script>
  var array='${test}'
</script>
```

**Update**

You should place your configurations in servlet context as it's accessed throughout your web application including in jsp files & also will not change until you restart your application.

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
Properties prop= new Properties();
prop.load(context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/filename.properties"));
String[]configArray= prop.get("words.for.js").toString().split(",");
context.setAttribute("configArray", myConfigArray);
```

or if your using [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)

```
ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
ctx.setAttribute("configArray", myConfigArray);
```

Comment: Probably the array is dynamic. He is asking how to send the array to the front-end, not how to access it.